# Вертикальное выравнивание TextInputEditText в TextInputLayout Material Design

Tags: java, android, material-design

В material design описано все красиво и работает по картинкам все красиво, только на практике немного иначе работает. TextInputEditText находится внизу, а не по центру по вертикали, за счет этого получаются огромные текстовые поля. Как это можно исправить?

Использую api 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
Используя библиотеку 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' не решает данного вопроса.

UPD: добавил изображения

[image: Пример]

Comment: добавьте картинки как выглядит у Вас и как должно быть.

Comment: Добавил изображение для примера

Comment: Может padding нужно добавить?

Comment: Не вариант, ибо texthint будет очень высоко отображаться чуть ли не выходя за фон TextInputLayout

Comment: А по `Guidelines` точно используется `TextInputEditText`,  а не простой `EditText` ?

Comment: Безусловно, вот пруф: https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-input-layout/ пробовал и с EditText